# Extending from GtkBin

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, gobject, custom-widgets

I'm trying to make a custom widget that resembles the "quick search" entry that Gtk uses on all TreeView-like widgets.

Here's a simplified example of my initial idea:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class QuickSearch(Gtk.Bin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuickSearch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add(Gtk.Entry())

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
search = QuickSearch()
win.add(search)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

The problems are the following:

- If I use it alone, as in this example, there seems to be space allocated to the custom widget, but the `GtkEntry` is not shown on the screen. I tried various combinations of properties on the `GtkEntry` and the custom widget (hexpand, vexpand, margins, aligns, etc) with no avail.
- If combined with other widgets, when I interactively query for the widget allocated height, it aparently is 1. On the screen, the widget effectively doesn't appear (since it's somewhat "squashed" between the other widgets).

So, there's something I'm missing on the object initialization or how I'm using this custom widget? Is this a problem specific to `GtkBin`? I tried doing the same with a `GtkBox` and works flawlesly, but I think `GtkBin` is better suited for this particular widget.

Comment: Why not just subclass `Gtk.Entry`?

Comment: The idea is that the widget haves a "border", the same as the mentioned quick search widget used in nautilus (Like [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/36017964/images/nautilus.png)). The other option is to draw that extra border myself, but given that case, I'll just extend GtkBox. The thing is that GtkBin was created to be extended like this, so the point in my question is to figure out *why* it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: In that case, why not look at how Nautilus implements that search widget?

Comment: That's beyond the point, I know how to implement it, and it's working with a GtkBox. The point of the question is **why I can't use GtkBin**. I would like to use that widget since its ideal for my implementation. I don't know what else I can say to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, `Gtk.Bin` is not allocating space to its child. If you implement the `do_size_allocate` virtual method then it works. Why the default implementation is not being called, I have no idea.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class QuickSearch(Gtk.Bin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuickSearch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add(Gtk.Entry())

    def do_size_allocate(self, allocation):
        self.set_allocation(allocation)
        child_allocation = Gdk.Rectangle()
        border_width = self.get_border_width()
        child_allocation.x = allocation.x + border_width
        child_allocation.y = allocation.y + border_width
        child_allocation.width = allocation.width - 2 * border_width
        child_allocation.height = allocation.height - 2 * border_width
        self.get_child().size_allocate(child_allocation)

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
search = QuickSearch()
win.add(search)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

However, I think inheriting from a `Gtk.Frame` is more appropriate for your purpose; it is a one-child container with a styleable border around it, which is what you want and more. And its size allocate method works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try it out(both this workaround and using GtkFrame) and see what works better in my case :3